# Sequence incrementing every 4 id's instead of every 1 like I set it to. Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I am new to SQL and Oracle so for practice, I have created a dummy table I made to track my typing learning sessions(because I never learned to type so i'm making up for it now), and set a sequence up using this query in Oracle:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE seq_keyboard_learning
MINVALUE 1
START WITH 1
INCREMENT BY 1
CACHE 10
```

My intent was for my id column to increment by  but it jumped from 1 to 5, etc every time i add a new value. For completeness, here are some of the queries i used when setting up this table.

```
CREATE TABLE keyboard_learning
(
emplid NUMBER CONSTRAINT emplid_pk PRIMARY KEY
,WPM NUMBER
,date_completed DATE
)

CREATE SEQUENCE seq_keyboard_learning
MINVALUE 1
START WITH 1
INCREMENT BY 1
CACHE 10

INSERT INTO keyboard_learning (emplid,wpm,date_completed)
VALUES (seq_keyboard_learning.nextval,15,'12-JUN-2012')

UPDATE keyboard_learning 
SET emplid = 1
WHERE emplid = 4

ALTER TABLE keyboard_learning
ADD attempt VARCHAR2(45)

INSERT INTO keyboard_learning
VALUES (seq_keyboard_learning.nextval,26,'6-JUN-2012','ASDFJKL:',2)
```

instead of incrementing every 4 terms, how can i adjust? Thanks

Comment: The numbers generated from a sequence are NOT guaranteed to be gap-free. It is peculiar that you're getting consistent gaps, but not an error. Are you perhaps running in a RAC environment? What "problem" is this causing for you?

Comment: So the first insert got 4, you updated that to 1 in the table, and the second insert got... what, 5 (which would be expected, though as Adam says not guaranteed) or 8 (which would be odd)? If it was 5, it did increment by 1 - from the value of 4 you got from the sequence previously, the manual edit of the table value is irrelevant. That would still leave the question of what happened to sequence values 1-3; I'd guess you tested the sequence before the first insert you show...?

Comment: yes i went ahead and added a second row manually, thinking the emplid would be 2 but it is 5

Comment: Perhaps my cache of 10 threw it off?

Comment: The cache isn't a problem, no. Since the first `emplid` was set to 4 from the sequence, the second `emplid` from the same sequence could only be 5 (or above). You show two `.nextval` calls, the first got 4, the second got 5, which is expected; the fact you updated the table to 1 has no bearing, that doesn't reset the sequence. You've 'lost' values 1 to 3, possibly from earlier `.nextval` calls you haven't shown, and you can't get them back without recreating the sequence and starting again. But gaps are allowed in the sequence - starting your `emplid`s at 4 shouldn't matter.

Comment: so i'll go add another row and that could possibly start me back on the right track to where i'm incrementing by 1? i'll try that

Comment: Remember that you are creating a surrogate key here which should have no meaning. You can't even really infer the exact order that rows were inserted. Plus since your sequence can assign numbers up to 28 digits long, you're unlikely to run out even if there are some gaps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ensuring you have a no gap sequence is basically impossible.  Keep in mind, a get from a sequence is an atomic operation, so if you go to insert a record and encounter an error, the sequence will still get incremented.  See below example.

Having a cache can also cause you to "lose" sequences.  If I specify a value of 10 in my cache, the database will cache 10 from the sequence.  If you only insert 2 rows and shutdown the database, the other 8 are discarded.  Note: Edited with correction by Alex Poole.

I hope this helped understand some of the behavior of sequences.

```
create table test
(id     number,
my_date date);

select seq.currval from dual;

insert into test
(id, my_date)
values (seq.nextval, 'foo'); -- will throw an exception

select seq.currval from dual;
```

Which results in:

```
table TEST created. 
CURRVAL
-------
      1 


Error starting at line 31 in command: insert into test (id, my_date) values (seq.nextval, 'foo') Error report: SQL Error: ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected
01858. 00000 -  "a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected"
*Cause:    The input data to be converted using a date format model was
           incorrect.  The input data did not contain a number where a number was
           required by the format model.
*Action:   Fix the input data or the date format model to make sure the
           elements match in number and type.  Then retry the operation. 
CURRVAL
-------
      2
```

Comment: The cache isn't at session level, it's held in the SGA. Two concurrent sessions can get sequential values, as can a subsequent session. Cached values are generally only 'lost' if the DB is bounced, though it can also happen at other times, e.g. if the cache is aged out of the SGA. Gaps for other reasons - errors, rollback, RAC - are more common, and entirely to be expected. And you can't rely on seeing them in a particular order, particularly in RAC.